# Barra de propriedades e banco de dados para PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

O **PhpStorm** possui **barra de propriedades** e **banco de dados** similar ao dreamweaver? Caso sim, como ativar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O PHPStorm tem tem uma ferramenta de Banco de Dados que você pode acessar em **View > Tool Windows > Database**

Quanto à Barra de Propriedades não há nada semelhante porque o propósito do PHPStorm não é ser um *construtor de sites*. As ferramentas da barra de propriedades lidam com **estilos**, que o PHPStorm infere que você irá construir usando arquivos `CSS` ao invés de diretamente no HTML.